# How to use tabBar without tabBarController in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I Use the following code to check which tab is selected in `TabBar` in `UIViewController` not using `UITabBarController`, But i don't know how to load the Particular ViewController in the View, Or is there any other way to achieve this

This is what i get from the Google and other forums, I use the Tag for the `UITabBarItems` to differentiate the buttons

```
import UIKit

class AdminViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController();
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:";
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer());
    }
    tabbar.delegate = self;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    println(item.tag);
    if(item.tag == 1)
    {
        //Want to load UIViewController into the CurrentViewController
    }
}

}
```

I have another idea, But it is not good
Place the `TabBar` in all `UIViewControllers` and When the `TabBarItem` is Clicked i will Navigate to that `UIViewController` using PerformSegue & There also a `TabBar`

Comment: Why don't you use `UITabBarController`?? It's behavior is exactly what you want to achieve, isn't it?

Comment: In my application i used `UINavigationController` With `SWReaveal` for Sidebar, In that this is one of the `UIViewController`, So i Cannot use `UITabBarController`, Any Suggestions???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Oliver Borchert I used the tab bar controller
This solved my problem completely

[TabBarController with SWRevealViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614851/tabbarcontroller-with-swrevealviewcontroller)

Thanks @Anbu.Karthik