# SWRevealViewController with a TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to add a slide out menu to my tabBarController using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). This is how I configured my storyboard:
[image]
Nothing happen when I click the button in the first viewContolloer (top right corner).

```
    @IBOutlet var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()




          if self.revealViewController() != nil {
          menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
          menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


          // Uncomment to change the width of menu
          //self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
         }
   }
```

I tried to add a Nav Controller to the tab bar as [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614851/tabbarcontroller-with-swrevealviewcontroller?rq=1), but nothing happened.

both front and rear VC are set correctly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you properly set the front and rear view controllers?

Comment: Which view did you see when the app launches?

Comment: I think I did.... The app launches correctly and I see the first view Controller but the button doesn't work.

Comment: Well I always forget some configurations which cause this to not work properly. So please cross check that you have properly set the front and rear vc’s as mentioned in the documentation.